# Jmeter : Error when I try to get data from Database using beanshell assertion

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to extract the results from my JBDC Request sampler using Bean shell assertion

I added a beanshell assertion to my sampler to extract the results and I got an error while running it.
The Code in question is :

```
if (!ResponseCode.equals("200") || vars.getObject("dataFromDB").size() == 0) {

FailureMessage = "!!!!!!!!!!! No connection to the database or data not 
received !!!!!!!!!!!";
Failure = true; 
prev.setStopThread(true):

}
```

Where dataFromDB is the result variable name of my JBDC Request Sampler

The Error is :
    Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error 
    invoking bsh method: eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems with your code:

1. `FailureMessage` definition should be at one line or you should [concatenate 2 strings on 2 lines](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/combine-two-strings)
2. `prev.setStopThread(true);` should end with the [semicolon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon)

Additionally:

3. Ensure that your `vars.getObject("dataFromDB")` expression doesn't produce `null`
4. Surround your code in [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) so if anything goes wrong - you will see the relevant message in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)

Assuming all above the suggested fixes would look like:

```
try {
    if (!ResponseCode.equals("200") || vars.getObject("dataFromDB").size() == 0) {
        FailureMessage = "!!!!!!!!!!! No connection to the database or data notreceived !!!!!!!!!!!";
        Failure = true;
        prev.setStopThread(true);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Script failure", ex);
}
```

---

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for any form of scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial), the required code amendments would look like:

```
if (!prev.getResponseCode().equals("200") || vars.getObject("dataFromDB").size() == 0) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("!!!!!!!!!!! No connection to the database or data notreceived !!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have tried the above and found it working ! Also thanks a lot for enlightening me about using Groovy. I am a beginner and I had no idea about it !